# How to declare 2d matrix array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

Here's a piece of PHP code that should declare 2D Array.

```
$array = array(
    range(1, 4), 
    range(1, 4)
);

print_r($array);
```

It should look like this:[image: Array]

But the output is:
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) )`

So what am I doing wrong? How can I declare\display as a matrix 2d array?

Comment: @splash58 Please do not post answers as comments.  Please post your method as an answer, so SO readers don't have to check comments for all possible solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You adding range only to first 2 indexs.

```
$array = array(
 range(1, 4), 
 range(1, 4),
 range(1, 4), 
 range(1, 4)
);
```

If you want better option:

```
$matrix=  array();

foreach (range(1,4) as $row) {
 foreach (range(1,4) as $col) {
  $matrix[$row][$col] = "some val";
 }
}


print_r($matrix);
```

For HTML output

```
<table border="1">
<?php foreach (range(1,4) as $row) { ?>
<tr>
<?php foreach (range(1,4) as $col) { ?>
<td><?php echo $row.$col; ?></td>
<?php  } ?>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: okay, i got it, but can you help me with output this one as in the pic?

Answer (score 1):

Found a (shorter) alternative in a [PHP doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) comment. Interesting as it is a one liner and `4` can be replaced by a variable:

```
$array = array_fill(1, 4, array_fill(1, 4, ''));
```